# Using Cufon in Userscripts

Tags: javascript, userscripts, cufon

I import JS files with this function:

```
function importScript(url){
var tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.type= "text/javascript";
tag.src = url;
document.body.appendChild(tag);
}
```

So:

```
importScript("http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cufon/1.09i/cufon-yui.js");
importScript("https://raw.github.com/gist/3160278/0895dcf14f623abba82c4aa7d25e00e50404248a/Meta.js");
```

That's just okay. I see script files in source with this code pieces. Everything works fine. But when I call Cufon:

```
Cufon.replace('h1');
```

Chrome console says: **Uncaught ReferenceError: Cufon is not defined**

Answer (score 2):

The method you are using loads the scripts asynchronously, so the following piece of code:

```
Cufon.replace('h1');
```

runs before the Cufon library has been loaded.

---

Instead, pass in a callback, and use `onload`:

```
function importScript(url, callback) {
    var tag = document.createElement("script");

    tag.type = "text/javascript";
    tag.src = url;

    callback && (tag.onload = callback);

    document.body.appendChild(tag);
}

importScript("http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cufon/1.09i/cufon-yui.js", function() {
    importScript("https://raw.github.com/gist/3160278/0895dcf14f623abba82c4aa7d25e00e50404248a/Meta.js", function() {
        Cufon.replace('h1');
    });
});
```

This can get out of hand rather quickly. I'd suggest you look into using a [Script Loader](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/for-your-script-loading-needs/).

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/72Ghd/

Comment: I don't know anything about "callback" and this thing does not work.

Comment: @UfukSarpSelçok - My bad. Updated. It should work now. Check out [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/72Ghd/).

Comment: No, that did not. Would @run-at make a difference? Because I haven't defined any. The same error BTW.